# Headphones with embedded micro that supports both 2.4GHz wireless and bluetooth

Tags: linux, wireless, bluetooth, headphones, microphones

I am looking for headphones that include all these features (basically TV headphones that can do bluetooth headphones too):

- Base to put on for charging
- Embedded microphone, or slot for plugging
- One base communicates via 2.4GHz wireless communication (like the
  gaming headsets)
- Headphones are usable via bluetooth for smartphone calls in outdoors

Optional great features would be:

- Base plug supported in
- Remote controller on the headphones (start/pause, previous/next/volume up and down)
- suited for large ears (ear size 7*4cm)
- can handle 2 different bluetooth sources
- can handle a bluetooth source and a 2.4GHz wireless source

It's been a week that I'm searching for a model that matches these specs but couldn't find anything. Do you guys have something in mind?

Answer (score 0):

The [SteelSeries Arctis Pro Wireless](https://steelseries.com/gaming-headsets/arctis-pro-wireless) may be what you're looking for:

- It has a proprietary 2.4 Ghz wireless signal and base station with a variety of connection options; Support for Linux is as good as your soundcard's Linux support. But the USB connection should be plug and play too.
- It supports Bluetooth sound simultaneously with the base station.
- It comes with two quick-swappable batteries instead of a charging dock.
- It has a retractable microphone built-in.
- It supports Bluetooth multipoint, but can only connect to one Bluetooth source at a time.